# How to Use IWorkspaceFactoryLockControl in Java

Tags: arcobjects, java, feature-class

I have tried to convert the interface but failed.

```
IWorkspaceFactory2 pWorkspaceFactory;
pWorkspaceFactory = new CadWorkspaceFactory();
ipWsFactoryLock = (IWorkspaceFactoryLockControl)pWorkspaceFactory;
```

It's failed when I use java.
I also tried the way to use the keyword **NEW** like this:

```
IWorkspaceFactory2 pWorkspaceFactory;
pWorkspaceFactory = new CadWorkspaceFactory();
ipWsFactoryLock = new IWorkspaceFactoryLockControlProxy(pWorkspaceFactory);
```

And I failed again.How can I use this method to release FeatureClass in **Java**

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? releasing a feature class is different from enabling/disabling schema lock?!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.My ultimate goal is to release the FeatureClass object I have created.Although I have tried to use the com.esri.arcgis.interop.Cleaner.release() method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with this code is that the CAD workspace does not support the `IWorkspaceFactoryLockControl` interface.

Below is some VBA testing different Workspace factories, some work CAD does not.

```vb
Public Sub test()
    Dim pWSF2 As IWorkspaceFactory
    Set pWSF2 = New FileGDBWorkspaceFactory ' works
    Set pWSF2 = New ShapefileWorkspaceFactory ' works
    Set pWSF2 = New CadWorkspaceFactory ' Fails
    Dim pWorkspaceFactoryLockControl As IWorkspaceFactoryLockControl
    Set pWorkspaceFactoryLockControl = pWSF2
    pWorkspaceFactoryLockControl.DisableSchemaLocking
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks,I have tried the FileGDBWorkspaceFactory too and it works well.